# Translating standard form of EOS to its polynomial form

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, chemistry

Is there a standard form for an equation like the others such as PR/SRK/... .

```
Z = (v - a b) / (v - b) - a / ((RT^1.5) (v + 2.6382 b))
```

for predicting pure substances vapor pressure? I need the polynomial form of the EOS and also the fugacity coefficient. How can I translate this EOS to its polynomial form?

Comment: You could `MultiplySides[]` by the `Denominator[]`.  Do you want `RT^1.5` ultimately in the rationalized form `RT^3`?  (I'm not a chemist and I'm not sure that a chemist means the same thing by "polynomial form" as a mathematician.)

Comment: `With[{eq = 
   Z == (v - a b)/(v - b) - 
       a/((RT^(3/2)) (v + HoldForm[2.6382] b)) /. {1/RT^(3/2) -> 
       1/u} // Rationalize},
 Simplify@
     MultiplySides[# == 0, Denominator@#, 
      Assumptions -> Denominator@# != 0] &@
   Together[RT^3 - u^2 /. First@Solve[eq, u]] /. HoldForm -> N
 ]`?